# $L^\infty$ bound on integral of product of $L^2$ and $C^\infty_c$ functions.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is open and bounded. Let $g \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$. Let
\begin{equation*}
h(x,x',y,y') := \frac{1}{(|x-x'|^2+|y-y'|^2)^r} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} g(t)(( f(x'+t)-f(y'+t))^2-(f(x+t)-f(y+t))^2) dt.
\end{equation*}
I wonder if $\exists r > 0$ such that $h \in L^\infty(\Omega^4)$.

I've been able to bound some of the terms, but when I expand the products, the mixed terms are problematic for me. Here is my approach for the pure terms:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
&\int g(t) [f^2(x'+t)+f^2(y'+t)-f^2(x+t)-f^2(y+t)] dt \\
&= \int f^2(t) [g(t-x')+g(t-y')-g(t-x)-g(t-y)] dt \\
&\leq C \int f^2(t) (|x'-x|^2+|y'-y|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
&= C \| f \|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)} (|x'-x|^2+|y'-y|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} 
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
where the second to last line follows by the Holder continuity of $g$. For the mixed terms I've been playing around with adding and subtracting terms, but I'm not having a lot of luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.